# Merge images in Java

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage, graphics2d, javax.imageio

I am trying to merge two images in Java. The two photos must be positioned horizontally (the first to the left of the second).
I think I have problems in the write method of the ImageIO class.

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;

public class Merge {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String p = "../../Desktop/temp/";
        BufferedImage left = ImageIO.read(new File(p+"006.jpg"));
        BufferedImage right = ImageIO.read(new File(p+"007.jpg"));
        BufferedImage imgClone = new BufferedImage(left.getWidth()+right.getWidth(), left.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D cloneG = imgClone.createGraphics();
        cloneG.drawImage(right, 0, 0, null);
        cloneG.drawImage(left, left.getWidth(), 0, null);
        System.out.println(ImageIO.write(imgClone, "jpg", new File(p+"001.jpg"))); //always false
        cloneG.dispose();
    }
}
```

`ImageIO.write(imgClone, "jpg", new File(p+"001.jpg"))` always returns false, I think there is something wrong here but I can't figure out what.
If I go into debugging I can see the merged photo, but then it won't be saved in the folder.

Comment: Maybe the image isn't ready? Maybe you should `cloneG.dispose()` before the call to write. It would help if you had example images, that you know cause the problem.

Comment: So, no exception is thrown? Per the ImageIO API, the `.write(...)` will return false if no appropriate image writer is found for the format name, here "jpg", which shouldn't happen.  So, what is returned if you do: `ImageIO.getWriterFormatNames();`? What String array do you see?

Comment: Also, you may be looking in the wrong location for the file, or the directory may not exist. I'd create the file on a separate line and print out its full path to help check this. When code is not working, best to break out your chained code and test each part.

Comment: If I put jpg in the "formatName" field, false is returned, if I put png instead, true is returned. Can you tell me the reason?
`ImageIO.getWriterFormatNames();` returns an array of strings, and jpg is present.

Comment: I can't explain the `false` being returned. In the array, is "jpg" capitalized the same as your own String? Or do you see uncapped and capped?

Comment: It should return both `jpg` and `JPG`

Comment: BTW (not THE problem) `drawImage(left, left.getWidth(), ... ` is probably wrong if the images are different sizes... probably meant to be `right.getWidth()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because JPEG doesn't support transparency, and you used ARGB as the image buffer type.  Removing the "A" worked for me.

```
 class Merge {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage imgClone = new BufferedImage( 50, 50, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        // returns "true"
        System.out.println(ImageIO.write(imgClone, "jpg", File.createTempFile( "Test-", "jpg"))); 
    }
}
```